# while loop c++ value initialization

Tags: c++, while-loop

had to make a while loop there the value of y is one positiv and one negative

my solution was:

```
int main ()
{
  int x = 5;
  double y = 1;


  while (x < 10)
  {
      x++;
      y *=  -1;

      cout << y << " " ;
  }
```

and my friends solution was:

```
 while (x < 10)
  {
      x++;
      y =  -y;

      cout << y << " " ;
  }
```

but i dont get how "y = -y" can get a positive value at the third output can anyone please explain it to me!

thx

Comment: `y *= -1;` and `y = -y` is **exactly** the same. It's basic math. `y *= -1;` is `y = y * -1;` is `y = -1 * y;` is `y = -y;`. You can skip the `*1` parts in maths.

Comment: *"i dont get how "y = -y" can get a positive value at the third output"* [It does not](https://godbolt.org/z/WzYn55).

Comment: i get this output on both code samples:     -1 1 -1 1 -1  , i mean how does it get positive value on forth (not third)  on my friends code.

Comment: It is because at first y = -(+1)=-1, on second loop y = -(-1)=1 and in third y = -(+1) = -1 and so on...

Comment: @deli_code Is it clear to you why the first example works? What difference do you expect between `y = -y;` and `y *= -1;`

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this. The expression `y *= -1` is **equivalent** to the expression `y = y * -1`, which is **equivalent** to the expression `y = -1 * y`, which is **equivalent** to the expression `y = -y`. These equivalencies are a matter of notation; there isn't anything profound to be learned here.